# How to call or invoke a Java program from EggPlant functional?

Tags: java, eggplant

I need to invoke a Java program inside a sensetalk script or from EggPlant.
Is there any possibility for doing the same?

Comment: I haven't worked with eggPlant before (first time I've heard of it!), but I found [these docs](http://docs.testplant.com/?q=content/using-eggplant), with a Java example. Is that what you're looking for? Is there anything in those docs you don't understand?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in mechanism for doing this. If you can package your java code as something that can be invoked through the command line you can use EggPlant's `shell` command to run the Java code as if it was invoked through the shell.

I know this is a clunky solution especially if you are wanting to pass data back and forth between Java and EggPlant but that's the only solution I was able to come up with when I was working with EggPlant.

http://docs.testplant.com/ePF/SenseTalk/stk-system-interaction.htm

Answer (score 2):

```
set destinationFile to "/Users/username/eggPlantTemp.txt"
shell "java -jar /Users/username/IdeaProjects/S3_tests/target/S3_tests-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ios > " & destinationFile

LogSuccess file destinationFile
```

You can use shell.
This command will execute jar (with parameter "ios"), record output in a file and then will show the file in eggPlant log.